Display Full 'Actions' Actions Column in LWC lightning-tree-grid Component
I would like to try to display the entire label of the actions column for the LWC lightning-tree-grid component.
Here is the screen of the issue
I am having quite a bit of difficulty using methods recommended in the documentation, such as the initialWidth attribute: 300.
Any suggestion ? Thanks very much!
